# is Increment/Decrement Optional in a for loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops

Is Increment/Decrement **Optional** in a for loop in JavaScript?

```
for(var i=0;i<10;)
{
  i++;
}
```

is this code valid?.

Comment: Yes. Why don't you just open the console, paste it, and see?

Comment: Everything is optional. `for(;;);` is valid code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes all 3 statements are optional. You can vary your for loop according to the output you want from it.
The following code would result in an infinite loop:

```
for(;;){
    // Code block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe so, for loops are designed to work well without this, you would just have to put it at the end of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Yes but this is classic for loop

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
// do somthing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Tested on W3School's preexisting code](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_loop_for), yes it is.

Clear it then paste the code below (or edit out the `i++` yourself):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript For Loop</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; ) {
  text += cars[i] + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop.

```
var i = 0;
while(i<10){
 i++;
}
```

Basically, it is the same just in my opinion looks a bit cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

There is a for loop that could be used and there is foreach as well. Reference example below:

const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

array1.forEach(element => console.log(element));

// expected output: "a"

// expected output: "b"

// expected output: "c"

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

In your case, it could be

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
numbers.forEach(number => console.log(number));
```